# Anchor peer vs CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Why should one use **Anchor peers** when the cross org communication can be acheived by setting **`CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT`** in every peer?

Can anyone explain the correct way one should be used?

Answer (score 5):

Let me clearly explains you

In the hyperledger fabric there are total Three Types of peers

- Endorsing Peers
- Committing Peers
- Orderer Peer (Orderer is also a
  Peer)

Something Hidden is:

- Anchor Peers
- Leader Peers

Anchor Peers are for cross-organization peer-to-peer communication, to setup Anchor Peers you need to setup Anchor Peers and use ENV

Step-By-Step

```
  - &org1
    Name: org1
    ID: org1MSP
    MSPDir: ./data/orgs/org1/msp
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: org1-peer
      - Port: 7051 

  # generate anchor peer transaction
  configtxgen -profile OrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./crypto-config/org1Anchors.tx -channelID publicchannel -asOrg org1
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to generate anchor peer update for maersksea..."
  exit 1org1     fi
```

> > Now you need to send a transaction inorder to setup Anchor Peers
> >     Check this >> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/commands/peerchannel.html#peer-channel-update

If you want to make other peers in your organization known to other organizations, you need to set the

CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT

**What They Do**:

High-level, peer-to-peer communication happens through gossip protocol and Anchor Peers are the key to gossip communication.

- Make sure peers in different organizations know about each other through gossip protocol.
- One Can use Private Data Concept using Anchor Peers because gossip distributes the private data peer-to-peer across authorized organizations, it is required to set up anchor peers on the channel

Read below mentioned docs
 - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html 
 - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/glossary.html

---

**LeaderPeers** are the main entry point for orderer to ship blocks to peers

One can set up leader Peers or Peers can elect one by its own

Two Types

- Static leader election
- Dynamic leader election

**Static leader election**

Static leader election allows you to manually define one or more peers within an organization as leader peers. Please note, however, that having too many peers connect to the ordering service may result in inefficient use of bandwidth.

```
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=false
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
```

**Dynamic leader election**

Dynamic leader election enables organization peers to elect one peer which will connect to the ordering service and pull out new blocks. This leader is elected for an organization’s peers independently.

```
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response but I do know what they do and what they are but i just wanted to know why use anchors explicitly when we can expose the peer endpoint directly for cross org communication?

Comment: Not all peers are responsible for cross communication and there should be one peer which does this and that is Anchor peer

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are 2 orgs in the network A and B. Each org has 2 peers.

ORGA-`peer1.orgA, peer2.orgA`

ORGB-`peer1.orgB, peer2.orgB`

Lets say peer1 is anchor peer in both the orgs.

When org A anchor peer(`peer1.orgA`) communicates with orgB anchor peer(`peer1.orgB`), then org A anchor peer will tell the org B anchor peer about the `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT` of other non anchor peer (`peer2.orgA`) and vice-versa.

So anchor peer shares the gossip endpoint of non anchor peers. So all the peers in the network know about all the other peers through anchor peers. And then peers can use the `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT` of another peer to communicate with that peer.