# Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode instantiation failure in newly joined Organisation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

We have a 2 Org Fabric network. Initially the channel which we are working on only had one Org "org1" defined, it was later extended to have two orgs by adding "org2".

Now we want to add the chaincode to the peers in "org2".

The chaincode can be installed, but when we instantiate it in "org1", it fails to be instantiated in "org2".

The only error we are able to see in the logs is a Gossip problem. The peers in "org2" cannot apparently join the Gossip network. When starting a peer in "org2", we see the following message in the peer log:

```
2019-08-28 13:48:41.804 UTC [gossip.comm] Handshake -> WARN 21b Authentication failed: Could not acquire policy manager for channel mychannel
2019-08-28 13:48:41.804 UTC [gossip.gossip] func1 -> WARN 21c Deep probe of peer0-org1-ch:7051 failed: Could not acquire policy manager for channel mychannel
```

It appears that there is an underlying problem in "org2" which is "Could not acquire policy manager".

Is this the root cause of the failure to instantiate the chaincode in "Org2"?

What is the policy manager and what leads to it being unavailable in "org2"?

Note that our genesis block was created only knowing "org1":

```
Profiles:
    MyConsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            MyConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    MyChannel:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Consortium: MyConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
```

Answer (score 0):

let me tell the concepts first,

In the hyperledger Fabric one can install chaincodes into peers and instantiate to the channel which is only time

Take this scenario:

Initial Setup:

One Org, two Peers and One channel
If suppose you install chaincode abc on two peers and instantiate on channel one time

Later If you add second Org to the channel and join second org peers then all you have to do is just install, no need for instantiation.

When you invoke or query with second org peers on the fly chaincode container will be created.

Make sure you have below-mentioned env in the peer for gossip to work properly

```
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=[org1-peer1:7051,org1-peer2:7051] #<a list of peer endpoints within the peer's org>
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=org1-peer2:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
```

I strongly recommend update anchor peers, check this [Anchor peer vs CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686480/anchor-peer-vs-core-peer-gossip-externalendpoint/57687945#57687945) I have mentioned clear instructions on updating anchor peers

Comment: Well that's the theory. In practice exactly not what happens.

Comment: I have done almost 7 production projects, and many times I have noticed it is working perfectly,  I am the witness it happens practically.

Comment: Just give me an aws ec2 instance I will show you a demo with sample org. My Skype ID: nnrthota

Comment: Unfortunately in this case, we get the message that the chaincode does not exist. I'm sure it will work once Gossip is working, the question is therefore about the Gossip problem.

Comment: I confirm that "CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true" and "CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false" are set. We do not currently have a configuration for "CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP". I will add it and update.

Comment: Try to add that and do let me know the status

Comment: Well, the problem has nothing to with the gossip and this answer is more misleading rather than providing a real picture.

Comment: @Artem Barger well the questions itself is misleading us, and reg: gossip I have given general instructions about gossip since he mentioned statement as. `Hyperledger Fabric Gossip authentication failure`

Comment: while answering the question it's better to point out to the real problem rather than trying to cover as much as possible information which continue to mislead and increase confusion.

Comment: @ArtemBarger you are right: I have updated the question to try to ask the real question that we want to get the answer to, rather than my interpretation of the observed symptoms. I have had to preserve the original question, so that the discussion about Gossip still has some sense.

Comment: `while answering the question it's better to point out to the real problem` >>> it depends on the user. @Artem Barger Iam not here to waste time with extra info. I am very optimistic and I want the user to get the full insight. @ISparkes mentioned question statement about `gossip` problem and question description about `chaincode` problem and i have answered for both Please read question statement & description always !!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it has nothing to do with Gossip initialization. You can instantiate chaincode per channel only once. Meaning that for second organization, in your case `Org2` you just have to wait until peer will get in sync and pull block which already contains instantiate transaction for your chaincode.

Now, to make it clear you need to instantiate Gossip for two particular reasons:

1. To allow cross organization state transfer for lagging behind peers or in case some org in network partition and cannot reach ordering service.
2. To enable private data as it distributed via gossip network across organization domains.

At any rate in you case the failure has nothing to do with Gossip per se. You just cannot instantiate chaincode twice.

If you would like to enable gossip you just need to update anchor peers for both of your organization, e.g. run config update transaction for each org publishing its anchor peers, which will be used to establish cross organization domain communication.

Comment: Thanks Artem for the clarification about Gossip. However, we've installed and instantiated *new* chaincodes on the same channel, and even created a new channel and installed the chaincode on it. The result is always the same: Org1 gets the new chaincode, Org2 doesn't.

Comment: @ISparkes what do you mean by saying Org2 doesn't have chaincode?

Comment: The chaincode in Org1 is installed and instantiated. In Org2 is installed but not instantiated

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by not instantiated, how do you check it? You send transaction to the peer from Org2 and it fails? Can you post logs from that peer? Did you wait until this peer will catch up with all blocks including the block which instantiates your chaincode?

Comment: We are checking it using "peer chaincode list --instantiated". We are instantiating from "org1". We have confirmed that the same block height is seen everywhere using the discovery cli.